# Parallel Docker Container Creation

Tags: docker

I am using a Docker Setup that consists of 14 different containers. Every container gets a `cpu_limit` of 2 and a `mem_limit` of 2g.

To create and run these containers, I've written a Python script that uses the `docker-py` library. As of now, the containers are created sequentially, which takes approximately 2 minutes.

Now I'm thinking about parallelizing the process. So now instead of doing (its pseudocode):

```py
for container in containers_to_start:
    create_container(container)
```

I do

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.map(create_container, containers_to_start)
```

And as a result the 14 containers are created 2x faster. BUT: The applications within the containers take a significant longer time to boot. At the end of the day, i dont gain really much, the time until every application is reachable is more or less the same, no matter if with or without multithreading.

But I don't really know why, because every container gets the same amount of CPU and memory resources, so I would expect the same boot time no matter how many containers are starting at the same time. Clearly this is not the case. Maybe I'm missing some knowledge here, any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

### System Specs

- CPU: intel i7 @ 2.90 GHz
- 32GB RAM

I am using Windows 10 with Docker installed in WSL2 backend.

Comment: Why are you using threads rather than processes?

Comment: What is the advantage of using multiple processes? Each container is created and started by making REST Calls to the Docker API Server, so sending these REST requests in parallel by using more threads seems logical to me.

Comment: I understand. I wasn't saying there was an advantage to using processes, I was merely asking what prompted you to use threads.